# Erro auth laravel com outra model?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-eloquent

Pessoal mudei o nome do model padrão do Laravel `User.php` para `Colaboradores.php` (claro, setei o `$table` e a `$primaryKey` no model), alterei também no `config/auth.php` a `model`. mas o login está sempre me retornando `false`, segue código de login:

```
'providers' => [
    'users' => [
        'driver' => 'eloquent',
        'model' => Siga\Colaboradores::class,
    ],

    // 'users' => [
    //     'driver' => 'database',
    //     'table' => 'users',
    // ],
],
```

---

```
public function auth( Request $request )
{

    $username = $request->input("usuario_colaborador");
    $password = $request->input("senha_colaborador");

    if( Auth::check() || Auth::attempt([
        'usuario_colaborador' => $username,
        'senha_colaborador' => $password]) )
    {
        // redirecionando usuário depois de logado
        return redirect(route('farol.meufarol'));
    }
    else
        return redirect(route('login'));
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Quando se utiliza uma outra classe que não segue o mesmo padrão de nomes de campos, existem formas de autenticar o usuário, [pela instância dessa classe](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/authentication#other-authentication-methods) ou [pelo Id do usuário](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/authentication#other-authentication-methods) como descrito na [documentação](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/authentication).

O código ideal nesse caso seria primeiramente trazer esse instância e conferir se os dados estão corretos, da seguinte forma:

```
public function auth( Request $request )
{

    $username = $request->input("usuario_colaborador");
    $password = $request->input("senha_colaborador");

    //busca o usuário para ver se o mesmo existe
    $model    = Siga\Colaboradores::where('usuario_colaborador',$username)->first();

    // confere se o usuário é a mesma senha
    if( Auth::check() || 
      ($model && Hash::check($password, $model->senha_colaborador)) )
    {
        // redirecionando usuário depois de logado
        Auth::login($model); // autenticando ...
        return redirect(route('farol.meufarol'));
    }
    else
        return redirect(route('login'));
}
```

*Basicamente seria essas as alterações, ou seja, como o método `attempt` deve seguir a mesma nomenclatura de nomes que são `email` e `password` na sua tabela é diferente do seu `model` de autenticação sempre vai retornar `false`.*

***Uma dica:*** se não for necessário, não mude o modelo padrão, porque o mesmo pode até ser adicionado novos campos e relacionamentos, e isso garante que todos os métodos proposto na [documentação](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/authentication) funcione como deveria.

<sub>**Referencias:**</sub>

- [Documentação](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/authentication)
- [Hashing](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/hashing)

Comment: Pô, show de bola, valeu Virgilio!!