# LARAVEL Login por email ou nome de usuario

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, login

Olá, estou desenvolvendo uma aplicação em Laravel 5.2.* e preciso implementar um sistema de login por nome de usuário ou login, alguém tem ideia de como configurar ou fazer este tipo de método?

Comment: Relacionado: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/162965/laravel-authatempt-sempre-retorna-false/162970#162970

Comment: Relacionado: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/206213/erro-auth-laravel-com-outra-model/206227#206227

Comment: Relacionado: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/148446/autentica%C3%A7%C3%A3o-costumizada-com-cpf-e-email/151477#151477

Comment: O sistema de autenticação já está pronto e configurado é só utilizar a própria documentação https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/authentication, mas, se tiver algo especifico pode [editar sua pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/212047/54880) e explicar melhor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode criar um novo método de login da seguinte forma:

```
public function authenticate( Request $request )
{
    $password = bcrypt( $request->input( 'password' ) );
    $login    = $request->input( 'login' ); // Email ou username

    if ( Auth::attempt( ['email' => $login, 'password' => $password] ) || Auth::attempt( ['username' => $login, 'password' => $password] ) ) {
        // Authentication passed...
        return redirect()->intended('dashboard');
    }
}
```

Comment: Não é a forma correta utilizar o poliformismo para isso. Veja que na Trait `Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\AuthenticatesUsers` exite o método `loginUsername`, o qual procura pela propriedade `username`, na qual não seja encontrada, é retornado o field `email` para ser utilizado para autenticação. Sempre que precisar de algo, olhe no core do Laravel.

Comment: @juniorb2ss por favor me esclareça uma dúvida, utilizando a propriedade username, o login poderá ser realizado por ambos os campos? Porque eu tinha entendido o seguinte, se utilizar a propriedade username o login seria realizado pelo campo que eu utilizar lá, se não ele usaria o email e não ambos os campos.

Comment: Leia o core. Se você colocar a propriedade `username` ele irá utilizar este field para a consulta, junto com o password. Se o padrão é `email` e `password`, você altera a propriedade `username` para login, a query será feita sobre as colunas `login` e `password`. Agora, se você quer complementar algo, também é possível, basta sobreescrever o método `credentials`, qual reserva quais campos vão para query.

Answer (score 1):

```
Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\AuthenticatesUsers
```

Troca a variável pelo campo que você quer autenticar

```
protected $username = 'username';
```