# Login e autenticação no Laravel 5.7

Tags: php, laravel

Estou desenvolvendo um projeto em Laravel, porém estou com dificuldade pra entender como funciona o login e autenticação do usuário para redirecionar para a dashboard.

Estou com uma tabela no banco chamada "usuario", que contem as seguintes colunas: id, nome, usuario, senha e email.

A autenticação tem que ser feita através do e-mail e senha, que já se encontram cadastrados. A senha está com hash MD5, sendo criada através do PhpMyAdmin.

Foi criado o AdminController. Segue abaixo:

```
public function index(Request $request){

    $credentials = $request->only('email', 'senha');

    if (Auth::attempt($credentials)) {
        // Authentication passed...
        return redirect()->intended('dashboard');
    } else {
        return redirect()->intended('index');
    }

    }
```

Foi criado também o Model Admin. Segue abaixo:

```
class Admin extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = ['nome', 'usuario', 'senha', 'email', 'admin'];
    protected $guarded = ['id','created_at', 'update_at'];
    protected $table = 'usuario';
    public $timestamps = false;
}
```

Porém, quando digito o usuário e senha da tela de Login, ocorre o seguinte erro:

Method App\Http\Controllers\DashboardController::store does not exist.

A minha view de Login está assim:

```
    <div class="account-pages mt-5 mb-5">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row justify-content-center">
                <div class="col-lg-5">
                    <div class="card">

                        <!-- Logo -->
                        <div class="card-header pt-4 pb-4 text-center bg-primary">
                            <a href="index.html">
                                <span><img src="site/img/logo-login.png" alt=""></span>
                            </a>
                        </div>

                        <div class="card-body p-4">
                            <form action="{{ url('dashboard') }}" method="POST">
                            {{ csrf_field() }}
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label for="emailaddress">E-mail</label>
                                    <input class="form-control" type="email" id="emailaddress" name="email" placeholder="Digite seu e-mail" autofocus>
                                </div>

                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <a href="pages-recoverpw.html" class="text-muted float-right"><small>Esqueceu sua senha?</small></a>
                                    <label for="password">Senha</label>
                                    <input class="form-control" type="password" name="senha" id="password" placeholder="Digite sua senha">
                                </div>

                                <div class="form-group mb-3">
                                    <div class="custom-control custom-checkbox">
                                        <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" id="checkbox-signin" checked>
                                        <label class="custom-control-label" for="checkbox-signin">Lembrar- me</label>
                                    </div>
                                </div>

                                <div class="form-group mb-0 text-center">
                                    <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit"> Entrar </button>
                                </div>

                            </form>
                        </div> <!-- end card-body -->
                    </div>
                    <!-- end card -->


                </div> <!-- end col -->
            </div>
            <!-- end row -->
        </div>
        <!-- end container -->
    </div>
    <!-- end page -->
```

@endsection

Quais são os próximos passos que devo realizar? Alguém pode me ajudar nessa?

Comment: Já existe a rotina para isso, porque fez assim? inclusive acho que é repetida sua duvida

Comment: Exemplo 1: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/162965/laravel-authatempt-sempre-retorna-false/162970#162970

Comment: Exemplo 2: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/206213/erro-auth-laravel-com-outra-model/206227#206227

Comment: Vi que tem o Auth para realizar autenticação, mas gostaria de entender melhor como funciona. Tem como me ajudar nisso? 

Se estiver repetido, tem como me mostrar onde posso encontrar? Comecei a pouco tempo a mexer com Laravel. Estou estudando ainda. Se puder me ajudar, agradeço

Comment: Opa, Show. Muito obrigado, Virgilio!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Só pra entender, qual seria o objetivo de fazer dessa forma? A documentação do Laravel é muito boa, assim que vc executa o comando php artisan make:auth ele já cria todo o sistema de autenticação para vc. Ele já cria o AuthController, protege as rotas através do middleware e etc.
https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/authentication
p.s. Senha em MD5? Por segurança utilize o padrão do laravel com o bcrypt.

Comment: É que sou novo em Laravel. Estou desenvolvendo o projeto justamente para aprender. Achei que o Laravel não tinha essa rotina, como já tem, achei ótimo.